# Angulay Flex Layout Custom break points don't work with SSR

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout, server-side-rendering

I need only two break points in Angular Flex Layout. So, I defined:

```
const CUSTOM_BREAKPOINTS: BreakPoint[] = [{
  alias: 'lg',
  mediaQuery: '(min-width: 700px)',
}, {
  alias: 'sm',
  mediaQuery: '(max-width: 700px)',
}];

export function getCustomBreakpoints() {
  return CUSTOM_BREAKPOINTS;
}

@NgModule({
  providers: [{
    provide: BREAKPOINTS,
    useFactory: getCustomBreakpoints
  }]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This works fine without Server Side Rendering. Once I enable it, my layout is no longer responsive. General rules are applied to build and run it as [here](https://angular.io/guide/universal#build-and-run-with-universal).

When I run this project with SSR, I'm always getting the layout layout with three central row section in the middle area instead of having all content in one column.

Without my custom break points, Angular Flex Layout works correctly.

So, my question, why did I implement incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, my approach does not work with AOT in general. After taking a look at the [BREAKPOINTS token](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/blob/b3f3404d11476b2a2a68b14dcabcd40f1753c123/src/lib/core/breakpoints/break-points-token.ts#L24) implementation in Angular Flex Layout, I found that it injects an array of breakpoints by using the BREAKPOINT token. So, I provided my list with this token:

```
{
    provide: BREAKPOINT,
    useValue: CUSTOM_BREAKPOINTS
}
```

Then, I saw that they merge my custom array with the default breakpoint array unless the DISABLE_DEFAULT_BREAKPOINTS token is disabled. So, I disabled it:

```
{
    provide: DISABLE_DEFAULT_BREAKPOINTS,
    useValue: true
}
```

After this, everything works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It appears supplying custom breakpoints is something that's in flux right now for the @angular/flex-layout library. This git issue:

https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/821

indicates that they're waiting to update the documentation after a new major change is completed.

However, there are apparently two ways to customize the breakpoints, either with the BREAKPOINTS token provider as you've mentioned, or by passing them in as arguments to the FlexLayoutModule:

```
FlexLayoutModule.withConfig({}, CUSTOM_BREAKPOINTS),
```

The second way is working for me with Angular 8 and @angular/flex-layout@8.0.0-beta.25

See the Configuration page in the wiki for more - https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/blob/master/guides/Configuration.md